Connection Time Out running tests on Selenium
I use Python 3.10, Pytest, Selenium, Geckodriver(Firefox) and X-dist for asynchronous tests. Not so long ago, I ran into a problem: when running tests, some of them pass and then the tests start giving the error: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Navigation timed out  after 30000 ms. And at the same time, my Internet connection completely disappears (in other browsers, as well as applications, there is no access to the network). The problem is only on my PC, there are no errors in the code.: they work in synchronous mode without any problems. I checked on a laptop in 2 streams: everything works flawlessly. What could be the problem? I run it in 6 threads, until recently there were no problems at all.
Already tried on other device - code works (2 streams).
Tried other router - same troubles.
Run tests with 6 streams, CPU R5 5600x. Connection trouble only when i'm starting tests, in a simple using (netsearch/games/other) i have no problems with internet. IDK what to do, no ideas(
GeckoDriver writes Falling back to a synchronous message, selenium says Navigation timed out.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
